# Object keeps moving between frames even though theres no frames in between?

Tags: animation, dopesheet

I'm new to Blender and I had been having some problems with animating. I animated the door at the start and then I went forward about 30-40 frames I then started animating the door again. When I play the animation, there were movements between the start and the end of the both animation even though there were not any frames in between.
[image]

Look at the 'Door:Wood' section on the dope sheet and you can see there is blanks between the 4 frames and yet the door is moving during the blank space.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Even though you have no keyframes on frame 178, there are keyframes for LocRotScale before and after. so frame 178 is in the middle of the interpolation between two keyframes with different values. To have the door steady slect the previous keyframe press **T**and set the interpolation to **Constant**.

Comment: Can you upload your .blend file?

Comment: Sure, thanks alot Cegaton it fixed my problem :-).

Comment: Hi, Shady. I'm wondering whether you could help me with my lighting?. I'm still having trouble lighting up my indoor room.

Comment: Sorry for any problems, I tried contact ShadyPuck on the chat before but he doesn't seem to respond and the latest response I got was just then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though you have no keyframes on frame 178, there are keyframes for LocRotScale before and after.

so frame 178 is in the middle of the interpolation between two keyframes with different values.

To have the door steady select the previous keyframe press <kbd>T</kbd> and set the interpolation to Constant.